# Screenshot taken at Exception via Selenium PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, screenshot, screenshotexception

Once in a while I get an exception in my Selenium PhantomJS tests that includes the text below

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
```

So has the screenshot really been taken like the message says? where would this screenshot be saved at? I checked the program directory and no image was saved.

Answer (score 3):

In my implementation the folder is specified in the `App.config` file, like so:

```
<add key="ScreenShot.FolderPath" value="..\\..\\..\\TestProject\\Screenshots\\" />
```

This is helpful when you have your [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server running the auto tests. So the XML poke will look like this:

```
<XmlPoke XmlInputPath="TestProject\App.config"
             Query="//appSettings/add[@key='ScreenShot.FolderPath']/@value"
             Value="$(ScreenShot.FolderPath)"/>
```

And finally in your code you point where the actual screenshots to be saved:

```
var screenshotDriver = IWebDriver as ITakesScreenshot;
if (screenshotDriver != null)
   {
     var screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
     screenshot.SaveAsFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScreenShot.FolderPath"] 
                           + screenShotName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);                          
   }
```